# How to change firefox preferences (about:config) using the new WebExtensions api?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

To change the settings (about:config) with the old API you would simply do:

```
require('sdk/preferences/service').set('media.webrtc.debug.multi_log', true);
```

I can't find anything on the subject for the new WebExtensions add-ons of Firefox. Is it not available yet?

Comment: You can't (yet) ! Use jetpack for that until someday accesses to about:config are granted. Your alternative is to use storage to log persistent configurations across sessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible, and likely, never will be.

Source: official WebExtensions FAQ https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/FAQ#Will_I_have_access_to_about:config_or_the_preferences.3F

Also, you might be interested in this discussion on mozilla-community.org: https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/webextension-read-write-access-to-about-config/12268

Comment: This really sucks, especially for browser settings that Mozilla doesn't offer extension APIs for. A big step backwards for addons.