# Can I use Services.prefs in WebExtensions for Firefox or is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using Firefox [preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service) API to set preferences in an Extension.

Specifically I am using `Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 2);` and `Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", value);`

I want to re-implement the extension using the new, recommended, WebExtensions Architectures.

On the documentation page of `preferences/services` it says:

> Don't use these techniques to develop new add-ons. Use WebExtensions
>   instead.

However, I don't sett any documentation for the equivalent, which would be [chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy#type-ProxyConfig) like this

```
var proxy_config = {
    mode: "pac_script",
    pacScript: {
        url: value
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({
    value: proxy_config,
    scope: 'regular'
}, function () { });
```

Can I still access the old `preferences/services` api in the new WebExtensions for firefox or is there a WebExtensions way in Firefox to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change firefox preferences (about:config) using the new WebExtensions api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241450/how-to-change-firefox-preferences-aboutconfig-using-the-new-webextensions-api)

Answer (score 0):

WebExtensions don't provide generic access to the underlying preferences service but there is work underway to implement the proxy api.  You can follow along here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283639