# Limit Print copies in Web App (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, printing, firefox-addon

I am trying to limit number of print copies in Firefox web page. If we can do one of below mentioned methods, we can achieve this;

1. Disable Print Dialog Box (print copies)
2. Silent Printing without any prompt.

I did silent printing with firefox as below;

- type `about:config` in address bar.
- Create new Boolean -> print.always_print_silent = true

It is working fine. But we should check always above value = true, or else it will appear the print dialog.
To do this our web app should verify this value before print command.

As I know it is not possible to read any preferences values with JavaScript(client side), I was planning to make a firefox Extension.

If anyone can give me an easy method of doing this, I really appreciate. 

**Any method to direct print or limit print copies to one in `print dialog box`**

Comment: FYI: This is not possible with a WebExtension. It is possible with other types of extensions. However, all non-WebExtension based extensions will be disabled in the release version of Firefox as of Firefox 57, scheduled for 2017-11-14.

Comment: If you have any kind of idea to limit print copies, I really appreciate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change firefox preferences (about:config) using the new WebExtensions api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241450/how-to-change-firefox-preferences-aboutconfig-using-the-new-webextensions-api)

Comment: I have no idea if this will help in your situation, but there is a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/) that lets you control printing via JavaScript. A while back, I needed to batch print about 2 million very large and complicated HTML documents to a PDF printer, and this add-on worked like a charm.